# boost timer usage question

Tags: c++, boost, time

I have a really simple question, yet I can't find an answer for it. I guess I am missing something in the usage of the boost timer.hpp. Here is my code, that unfortunately gives me an error message:

```
#include <boost/timer.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::timer t;
}
```

And the error messages are as follows:

```
/usr/include/boost/timer.hpp: In member function ‘double boost::timer::elapsed_max() const’:
/usr/include/boost/timer.hpp:59: error: ‘numeric_limits’ is not a member of ‘std’
/usr/include/boost/timer.hpp:59: error: ‘::max’ has not been declared
/usr/include/boost/timer.hpp:59: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
/usr/include/boost/timer.hpp:59: error: expected `)' before ‘double’
```

The used library is boost 1.36 (SUSE 11.1).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Additional info: `elapsed_max` is defined using `std::numeric_limits<std::clock_t>::max()` and `timer.hpp` header normally includes `<limits>` indirectly (though this may be off if using the `BOOST_NO_LIMITS` macro). Could we have to the full compile line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be fine, on a side note, are you sure you are typing `#include` instead of `include`?

You shouldn't need to, but you can try to also include:

```
#include <limits>
```

Before the boost include as it seems that may fix at least some of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The code certainly compiles for me using g++ and Boost 1.4.2 on Windows. Can you give us the version of your g++ compiler? Use `g++ --version`. This looks like one of those cases where something else is defining `max`, possibly as a macro.

Comment: I use: `g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.3.2 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 141291]`
and boost 1.36

Comment: @stefita You might want to upgrade both GCC and Boost on your system.